# How to construct a mathematical formula corresponding to the index with the presented values

Tags: javascript, react-native, mathematical-optimization

I have this function to centralize a item in `Flatlist` (horizontal):

```
centralizeItem = (index) => {
 const WIDTH = scale(95)
 let centerSize

 if (index === 0) centerSize = (WIDTH*1.5) * -1

 if (index === 1) centerSize = (WIDTH/2) * -1

 if (index === 2) centerSize = (WIDTH/2)

 if (index === 3) centerSize = (WIDTH*(index/2))

 if (index === 4) centerSize = (WIDTH*(index/2+0.5)) // 2.5

 if (index === 5) centerSize = (WIDTH*(index/2+1)) // 3.5

 if (index === 6) centerSize = (WIDTH*(index/2+1.5)) //4.5

  return centerSize
}
```

This formula return a Offset value to scroll in y-value using

```
this.refs.listRef.scrollToOffset({offset: this.centralizeItem(index) })
```

The above code fires when the item is selected

But, the `Flatlist` render a lot of data, not just 7 index, and this formula are impracticable.

I need a formula that follow the variations above in the function

Comment: whats the calculation for the remaining indexes? Will they just repeat the same throughout from 0-6 logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a formula and calculate the factor.

```
centralizeItem = index => scale(95) * (index - 1.5);
```